# Permission denied error while writing to a file in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a file and write some integer data to it in python. For example, I have a variable abc = 3 and I am trying to write it to a file (which doesn't exist and I assume python will create it on its own):

```
fout = open("newfile.dat", "w")
fout.write(abc)
```

First, will python create a newfile.dat on its own? Secondly, it's giving me this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'newfile.dat'
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Yes python have to create on its own, but can you see the folder permissions?

Answer (score 26):

Please close the file if its still open on your computer, then try running the python code.
I hope it works

Comment: The "w" mode looks correct for creating a file.  If not an open file, perhaps it's a permissions issue with the working directory?  What OS is the OP using?

Comment: If running something headlessly / opening with python, make sure there is a file.close()

Answer (score 18):

This also happens when you attempt to create a file with the same name as a directory:

```
import os

conflict = 'conflict'

# Create a directory with a given name
try: 
    os.makedirs(conflict)
except OSError:
    if not os.path.isdir(conflict):
        raise

# Attempt to create a file with the same name
file = open(conflict, 'w+')
```

Result:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'conflict'
```

Answer (score 13):

I've had the same issue using the cmd (windows command line) like this

```
C:\Windows\System32> "G:\my folder\myProgram.py"
```

Where inside the python file something like this

```
myfile = open('myOutput.txt', 'w')
```

The error was that when you don't use a full path, python would use your current directory, and because the default directory on cmd is

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

that won't work, as it seems to be **write-protected** and needs permission & confirmation form an administrator

Instead, you should use full paths, for example:

```
myfile = open('G:\my folder\myOutput.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that was my case.  I was using Windows Task Scheduler and a .bat file to run my Python script, was getting the permission error until I added the full path for the file.

Comment: use os.chdir(path) to set the cwd to where the file sits

Comment: Though not the case in the OP's question, you can also get a permission error if you specify an existing path without appending a file name as well.
It sounds basic, but where variables for paths exist, it can be easy to forget to append the filename to create the full path.. (*blushes*)

Comment: Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 11):

Permission denied simply means the system is not having permission to write the file to that folder. Give permissions to the folder using "sudo chmod 777 " from terminal and try to run it. It worked for me.

Comment: It may also mean that the file does exist but is not writable by you: in order to write to an already existing file you must first "delete" its contents, which implies write permissions to the existing file... I got into this situation today and I spent 30 minutes figuring what was happening, when it was this "simple".

Answer (score 6):

I write python script with IDLE3.8(python 3.8.0)
I have solved this question:
if the path is 
`shelve.open('C:\\database.dat')`
it will be 
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\database.dat.dat'`.
But when I test to set the path as 
`shelve.open('E:\\database.dat')`
That is OK!!!
Then I test all the drive(such as C,D,F...) on my computer,Only when the Path set in Disk

> C:\\

will get the permission denied error.
So I think this is a protect path in windows to avoid python script to change or read files in system Disk(Disk C)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How can you get write permission to C drive? I've tried masking without any luck. I'm making a tool that I'd like to install in `C:\Program Files` by default

Comment: I see the same in Windows 10. Trying to change permission to the folder under `C:` via git bash does not work. Fortunately, I have another drive mounted on `D:` and can write to that disk.

Answer (score 3):

In order to write on a file by using a Python script, you would have to create a text file first.
Example  A file such as C:/logs/logs.txt should exist.
Only then the following code works:

```
logfile=open(r"C:/logs/logs.txt",'w')
```

So summary.

> 1. A text file should exist  on the specified location
> 2. Make sure you close the file before running the Python script.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: yes, if the file is not there Python will create it.

Secondly, the user (yourself) running the python script doesn't have write privileges to create a file in the directory.

Comment: It was a permission error which is fixed now but still this error is coming up:
    TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: To write something other than a string, it needs to be converted to a string first. See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: to add to @RobertCaspary 's comment, you can use `str(abc)` to convert  to string. so `fout.write(str(abc))`

Comment: Different issue now. It should be a different question ;)

Comment: How can I get around the issue of write permissions denied after the creation of a directory from python?

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing the python script via terminal pass --user to provide admin permissions.

Worked for me!

If you are using windows run the file as admin.

If you are executing via cmd, run cmd as admin and execute the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have write permissions for that directory you were trying to create file by properties

Comment: Would help the OP to give an example

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue and i figured that the file is open in my pc and hence the permission denied issue , once i close the file . It would work

Answer (score 0):

I know that probably you've already solve this issue, but just in case:
My issue was related with the "path" definition when trying to dynamically create folders and sub-folders.
I try to pass the "path" directly to the df.to_excel, but you need to first add the file name into the path:

```
year = str(date_input.year)
month = str(date_input.month)
path = Path('../Project_Files/' + year + '/' + month)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
else:
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
path_final = os.path.join(path,'excel.xlsx')
df.to_excel(path_final, index=False)
```

And it works, without the error of "Permission denied"